# Mostrar y ocultar vistas con múltiple botones con VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify

Por ahora solo tengo un *button* que tiene la función de una condición que si es `true` abre la vista principal y si es `false` abre otra vista secundaria.
Mi problema surge al agregar mas *buttons* incluido con sus vistas, como logro hacer la misma función de abrir la vista principal y si es false abrir la vista que están en los demás buttons.

Lo que alcance a realizar fue que solo un button tenga la función de mostrar u ocultar una vista.

```
<v-btn class="headline boton-redondear" depressed large color="secondary"
       style="min-width: 17%;"
       v-on="on"
       @click="mostrarFiltro = !mostrarFiltro"
 >
  <v-icon small>fa-filter</v-icon>
</v-btn>


<!-- VISTA PRINCIPAL -->
<v-layout v-if="mostrarFiltro" row wrap class="scroll" pr-2>
   <p>TRUE</p>
</v-layout>

<!-- VISTA SECUNDARIA -->
<v-layout v-if="mostrarFiltro" row wrap class="scroll" pr-2>
   <p>FALSE</p>
</v-layout>


<!-- VUE -->
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      mostrarFiltro: true,
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Deberás de cambiar la variable que tienes como (`mostrarFiltro: true`,).
Así podrás tener varios botones con sus respectivas funciones de aparecer y desaparecer el contenido.
Ejemplo: en la variable booleano del botón `mostrarFiltro`, puedes declarar una variable similar como `mostrarFiltro2` y declararlo en tu VUEJS, de la misma forma como lo tienes en tu primer botón.